# Magento 2.0.4 Image Import problem

Tags: magento2, image

I am using Magento 2.0.4.

When I'm importing 2 test product thru csv file using the native magento importer , I have included one base image.

I thought Magento would create thumbnail and small image automatically. But in backend and front end thumbnail and small image are missing. Thus, I add the thumbnail and small image in `small_image`, `small_image_label`,`thumbnail_image`,`thumbnail_image_label` fields in my spreadsheet. But, the problem is thumbnail and small image also show up in product detail.

How can I eliminate thumbnail and small image in product detail? 
As far as magento do it automatically to generate them, I have installed "GD" but still no hope.

Answer (score 0):

Add this column to your csv import file:

**hide_from_product_page**

**file1-1.jpg,file0-0,jpg**

I am having issues with this though as some products have random images thrown into that area now. Also, I am using the amazon s3 for images, so I dont know if this is causing issues. Hope this helps.